# Logback is creating only 22 log files even if the max index is 300

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I have configured RollingFileAppender with FixedWindowRollingPolicy with maxIndex 300 but for some reason it is only creating 22 log files. I have tried searching but could not find related answers.

```
<configuration>
<property name="HOME_LOG"
    value="/home/ec2-user/production/logs/Test.log" />

<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>

    <file>/home/ec2-user/production/logs/Test.log</file>
    
     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>/home/ec2-user/production/logs/Test.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
    <minIndex>2</minIndex>
    <maxIndex>300</maxIndex>
</rollingPolicy>

 <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>

</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Comment: "When large values are specified by the user, the current implementation will automatically reduce the window size to 20." http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy

Comment: Thank you. I should implement **TimeBasedRollingPolicy** then.